# Which set of options takes precedence during upgrade to win10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade to win 10. I'm running the setup.exe file from a usb stick.

Before installation starts, it asks if I want to:

1. Keep files, apps & settings
2. Keep only files
3. Keep nothing

No matter which I choose, during installation it then asks if I want to perform:

1. Upgrade (keeping files, apps & settings)
2. Custom (a clean install, choose drive, etc)

These 2 sets of choices seem incompatible with each other.  If I wanted to Keep Only Files, there is no way to specify this in the second selection.

I actually want option 3 in the original selection. But I'm worried that the second set of options will overwrite the first. Or that if I choose Custom during the second selection, that it won't give me the free upgrade from 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to click `Custom Install` Windows would prompt you to reboot and do a custom install from there if you want to change the partition layout. If you don't want to touch the layout, you can quite happily go with `Upgrade` and Windows will do the in place upgrade and you will get Windows 10 for free. I personally haven't tried the `Custom` option, as I usually just clean install after upgrading anyway, and I didn't want to risk my free license.

The second set is like the second screen in the Windows 7 install, where it asks if you want to `Upgrade` or use a `Custom` layout. I still don't know why that's there though in the in place upgrade to Windows 10.

TL;DR: Click `Upgrade` if you aren't willing to risk it, otherwise, hit `Custom`.

Comment: In the end I selected Keep Nothing and then chose Upgrade. The end result was that my win10 install went fine and all the pre-upgrade documents were put in the windows.old folder.  Thanks for all your help today, much appreciated.